# php profile username display on web url

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating PHP profile username display on web URL script this script when i removed from username from web URL but not display error.php file

Here is my code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['username'])){
echo"";
}else {
header("location:error.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: you need a space after the colon in the header call `header("Location: error.php");`

Answer (score 0):

**You might have 2 problems here.**

**1. Are you completely removing the URL query of 'username'?**

Example:
If you have "www.example.com?username=" it will still be set and run the first block of the if statement.

**2. Is the header called before sending information to the client?**

header() has to be called before any HTML for it to work at all.

> ### header()
>
> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is > called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

If you wanted to redirect a user after sending them information you can use JavaScript:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] != ''){
    echo"";
}else {
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "error.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

Source: [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: your script working but when i removed user name master not display error file http://localhost/zblog/profile.php?username=maser name like this

Comment: Do you want it to display an error with localhost/zblog/profile.php?username=? Or do you want to display an error if the username is not valid?

Comment: i want to create username master when i removed it's display should be error file

Comment: This will show an error page if ?username doesn't equal 'master'. Is that what you want? Sorry its hard to understand what you are asking for.

<?php 
if(isset($_GET['username'])){
    if (isset($_GET['username']) != 'master')
       echo '<script>window.location.href = "error.php';</script>";
}else {
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "error.php';</script>";
}
?>

Comment: not working brother when i removed username but  not display error file

Comment: I have edited my code in my answer. Also since I solved your first problem could you mark my answer as solved? Thanks

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what your problem is. Can you please rephrase?